# Neutral numpy array index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I use a data structure which is a multi-dimensional numpy array. For some use cases, this array has `n`, and for other `n+1` dimensions. I want to keep the nice structure it has and not clutter the code with too many conditions, so I was wondering if there's a way to always use `n+1` indices and have the last index ignored by an indexing operation.

For instance the following should work equivalent:

```
# case 1 (n+1) - no neutral index required
a = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
last_index = 1
# this works
value = a[0, last_index]

# case 2 (n) - last index is neutral
a = np.asarray([1, 2, 3])
last_index = <neutral index>
# last_index will be ignored in this case
value = a[0, last_index]
```

Comment: What do you want `value = a[0, last_index]` in second case to return?

Comment: The same as if `last_index` was just ignore. In this case that would be `1`.

Comment: No, i mean what should happen when you access `a[0, last_index]` ?

Comment: As I said, `1` should be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [`Ellipsis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis)?  Normally I see it in the brackets, but this test shows it can be assigned to a variable

```
In [68]: i=Ellipsis
# i=... # works in Python3

In [69]: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,5]])[0,i]
Out[69]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [70]: np.array([1,2,3])[0,i]
Out[70]: array(1)

In [71]: np.array([1,2,3])[0,...]
Out[71]: array(1)
```

Comment: This looks promising. Does this also work in Python 2?

Comment: Awesome - works like a charm in Python 2.7.9. Thanks!